# Why does Pandas Transpose Fail Without Error?

Tags: python, pandas

When I perform a transpose of a Dataframe with one column and ~20 million rows, Pandas drops about 18 million cells without error or exception. Why?

I am not surprised that the data frame lost data -- it probably ran out of memory, but I would expect an error. This leads me to wonder if I am not understanding something vital about data frames.

In the following snippet of code, you can see that it displays and sums a column of data. It then transposes the column into a row, displays incorrect values, happily computes the wrong sum, and then merrily completes with no indication that something went wrong. Coincidentally, the two sums appear similar because they both begin with 1.5, but if you look closely you'll see they are off by an order of magnitude. I am running Anaconda Python 3.7.8 within Visual Studio Code on a Windows 10 64-bit system.

```
<Read in all of the Chicago taxi data from 2016 here...>
print('Isolating seconds...')
seconds = all_trips.iloc[:,3]
print(seconds)
print('Converting to int64...')
seconds = seconds.astype(dtype='Int64')
print(seconds)
print('Converting seconds series to data frame...')
pd_seconds = pd.DataFrame(seconds)
print(pd_seconds)
sum_seconds_column = pd_seconds.sum()
print('Sum of column: {0:.4e}.'.format(sum_seconds_column.values[0]))
print('Transposing column to row...')
# Loses data in the following line.
transpose_seconds = pd_seconds.T
print(transpose_seconds)
sum_seconds_row = transpose_seconds.sum(axis=1)
print('Sum of row: {0:.4e}.'.format(sum_seconds_row.values[0]))
```

The output is:

```
Isolating seconds...

0           180.0
1           240.0
            ...
1245710    2040.0
1245711       0.0
Name: trip_seconds, Length: 19866157, dtype: float64
```

Converting to int64...

```
0           180
1           240
           ...
1245710    2040
1245711       0
Name: trip_seconds, Length: 19866157, dtype: Int64
```

Converting seconds series to data frame...

```
0                 180
1                 240
...               ...
1245710          2040
1245711             0

[**19866157** rows x 1 columns]
```

Sum of column: **1.5235e+10**.

Transposing column to row...

```
0        1        ...  1975106  1975107
trip_seconds      900      240     ...      180        0
```

[1 rows x **1975108** columns]

Sum of row: **1.5395e+09**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you try taking sub-ranges of the original data and testing them separately? For example, if the error occurs when you use the first half of the data, but not the second, then the problem must have something to do with the actual data in the first half. On the other hand, if you can't reproduce the problem with data below a certain size no matter what you do, but the problem consistently occurs with larger data, then it actually is a memory size issue.

Comment: Took a little time but no issues with `pd_seconds = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 2000, (19866157, 1))).astype(dtype='Int64')` on my machine. Some more information about the dataset may be necessary as mentioned above. Try to isolate a reproducible example that replicates the issue.

Comment: Did you notice that your very first output shows a length of 19,666,157, but the last displayed row is 1,235,711?  That.s strange.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, I found the actual problem and a solution, if not an explanation. Thanks to the commenters for their suggestions to narrow down the problem. The code to create the large data frame looked like this:

```
january_trips_df = pd.read_csv('chicago_taxi_trips_2016_01.csv')
february_trips_df = pd.read_csv('chicago_taxi_trips_2016_02.csv')
march_trips_df = pd.read_csv('chicago_taxi_trips_2016_03.csv')
april_trips_df = pd.read_csv('chicago_taxi_trips_2016_04.csv')
may_trips_df = pd.read_csv('chicago_taxi_trips_2016_05.csv')
june_trips_df = pd.read_csv('chicago_taxi_trips_2016_06.csv')
july_trips_df = pd.read_csv('chicago_taxi_trips_2016_07.csv')
august_trips_df = pd.read_csv('chicago_taxi_trips_2016_08.csv')
september_trips_df = pd.read_csv('chicago_taxi_trips_2016_09.csv')
october_trips_df = pd.read_csv('chicago_taxi_trips_2016_10.csv')
november_trips_df = pd.read_csv('chicago_taxi_trips_2016_11.csv')
december_trips_df = pd.read_csv('chicago_taxi_trips_2016_12.csv')

all_trips = pd.concat([january_trips_df,february_trips_df,march_trips_df,april_trips_df,
    may_trips_df,june_trips_df,july_trips_df,august_trips_df,september_trips_df,
    october_trips_df,november_trips_df,december_trips_df])
```

Isolating the problem revealed that the index was not consistently numbered from 1 to ~20,000,000. To correct the index, I added the parameter `ignore_index=True` to the call to concat(), and the code worked fine and no data was dropped.

I tried to re-create the problem with a smaller data set but to no avail. I am not sure if I have stumbled across a bug or if transposing with an inconsistent index has an unexpected behavior (to me, anyway).